# slideUp() on second click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, slide

How can i `slideUp()` li element on second click?

I have tried with `.data()` for gathering number of clicks but this method is breaking my css(border) applied with jQuery.

```js
var paragraph = $('p');
var paragraphParent = $('li');

paragraph.addClass('displayNone');
    
paragraphParent.on('click', function () {
paragraph.stop().slideUp();
$(this).children().stop().slideDown();
});
```

```css
.displayNone{
    display:none;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;   
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li{
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}

li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </li>
    <li>Item 3
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </li>
    <li>Item 4
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is the code that counts the number of clicks? I assume that attempt would be more relevant.

Comment: have you try to use `slideToggle`?

Comment: Yes, and the behaviour is really weird, since it's replacing any "Item" with paragraph text.

@Jon 
`var $this = $(this);        
 var clickCount = ($this.data("click-count") || 0) + 1;
  $this.data("click-count", clickCount);`

Comment: just use bootstrap collapse instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
    paragraphParent.on('click', function () {
        paragraph.not($(this).children('p')).slideUp();
        $(this).children().slideToggle();
    });

   paragraph.on('click', function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
   });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hgwmLp4o/1/)

and for count you can use this code

```
var paragraph = $('p');
var paragraphParent = $('li');

paragraph.addClass('displayNone');
 paragraphParent.on('click', function () {
    paragraph.not($(this).children('p')).slideUp();
    $(this).children().slideToggle();
     // count number of clicks
     var click_num = parseInt($(this).attr('data-count'));
     $(this).attr('data-count' , click_num + 1);
     alert($(this).attr('data-count'));

});
paragraph.on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hgwmLp4o/4/)

Comment: I've tried this, but it's replacing everything that is not in `<p></p>` + sometimes it can break and don't show anything, like empty rectangle without even title.

Comment: @nehel  is this what you want?? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/hgwmLp4o/  .. you can check my updated answer and demo

Comment: Mmm yeah, seems like i will have to delete my headers since i forgot to add my snippet them... http://jsfiddle.net/hgwmLp4o/2/

Comment: @nehel  you can see updated answer with a new demo as well .. it may help for count you want .. Good Luck :)

Comment: Ya, already made few modifications in html and css and it works perfecto, thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. here i have used bootstrap collapse

```css
.displayNone {
    display:none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1"><a>Item 1</a>

            <p class="collapse" id="demo1">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </li>
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><a>Item 2</a>

            <p class="collapse" id="demo2">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </li>
        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo3"><a>Item 3</a>

            <p class="collapse" id="demo3">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The idea was to not type `id`, since i have around 20 of this `li` elements, but i sure will keep this in mind for further, smaller projects! Thanks! On the other hand i see that there is a little bounce effect when the collapsed item is sliding up. Is it intented?

Comment: yup its cool.  i just suggest you the simple way as there is only 4 <li> in example that you given.

Comment: sorry i do not have any idea about that effect.

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery `.data` API, as you tried.

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul li').find('p').hide();

  $('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var count = $(this).data('count') + 1;
    $(this).data('count', count)
    if (count == 2) {
      $(this).data('count', 0).find('p').stop().slideDown();
      $('ul li').not(this).find('p').slideUp();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-count="0">Item 1
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </li>
  <li data-count="0">Item 2
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </li>
  <li data-count="0">Item 3
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </li>
  <li data-count="0">Item 4
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```